# System Level Export Rest call for Azure API for FHIR

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I have setup Azure API for FHIR and a storage account. I successfully integrated the Storage account with FHIR by following this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/configure-export-data

Followed by the integration process, i issues the following rest command

```
import requests

url = "https://<fhir-server-name>.azurehealthcareapis.com/$export"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/fhir+json',
  'Prefer': 'respond-async',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

It returned a 202 response with empty body.. As soon as we send export command, the data would be stored inside our storage or we need to somehow specify the storage account information in our json to start the export process. Can someone clarify ?

Comment: when i check the logs, i am keep seeing some activity like, "List Keys", "List Storage Account Keys". Even in Monitoring->Insights i can see 336 transactions happened in last 4 hours.. Even charts are showing the spike.. However, availability is always 100% and no data is stored

Comment: i checked blob, tables, fileshare, queues. None of them has data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue the $export request, the response should have a `Content-Location` header with a URL to the status document for the export job. If you check that location should should see a status of what has been exported and a location of the files.

Comment: Actually i received an empty response :-(

Comment: Okie its there in the header - https://<fhir-server>.azurehealthcareapis.com/_operations/export/67f3faea-ed29-4132-9881-d170cdc0bd99. Does it mean that export happened to this storage container - 67f3faea-ed29-4132-9881-d170cdc0bd99 ?

Comment: Looks like, i didnt give permissions properly. It worked now. Thanks